# Changing blood values o female dog (ALT, ALKP) after infusion - liver cancer?

Tags: dogs, veterinarian, liver-disease

I have a dog that has not been eating well for a good two weeks. In the course of the treatment, it turned out that certain values in the dog's blood were elevated. These included alkaline phosphatase (ALKP-german abbreviation in brackets), alanine aminotransferase (ALT) and also bilirubin levels. After administration of an infusion over several days, whereby in each case only over two hours with a quantity of maximally 500 ml saline solution was infused, the values improved in each case. This meant for the liver-significant values (ALKP and ALT) that these returned to a measurable range just above an upper threshold value of the normal range and for the bilirubin even a return to the lower threshold of the normal range.
During an ultrasound-based examination, a history of chronic pancreatitis in mind, the examination revealed that the pancreas was spherically formed, contrary to its original flat appearance, so that a tumor could not be ruled out. However, according to the doctor, the rapid improvement of the blood values after the infusion contradicts a tumorous problem.
Today, another blood test was performed and the liver values, which had initially improved, were again outside the measurable range after cortisone had to be administered due to an inflammation in the leg. The bilirubin value, on the other hand, was only 0.1 above the upper threshold of the normal range, so there was not such a massive increase as in the liver values. All in all, however, I have the impression that the vet doesn't really have an idea what the exact problem could be. The dog is 12 years old, but based on the massive improvement after infusion and away from the mere theory that it could be a tumor, no further statement is actually made. I would therefore be interested to know what other reasons could be.
I would be very grateful if you could help me and I apologize if I am not sufficiently precise, as I have no biological training.

**Further informations:**

**Bullet point comments on the course of the disease:**

**Week one:**

- Deterioration of feeding behavior accompanied by excessive fluid intake.
- Towards the end of week one, cessation of feeding and only fluid intake (still excessive accompanied by disproportionately frequent urination).

**Week two:**

- blood test, which recorded a renal early detection value, liver values and especially bilirubin, which were elevated in each case
- then administration of several infusions for flushing, which led to a noticeable improvement of the blood values around Friday of the second week
- beginning in the night from Friday to Saturday fever as well as increased defecation
- followed by administration of fever reducers and medicine to calm the intestines, which brought relief for the time being

**Week three:**

- In the night to Monday, sudden massive limping on the left hind leg and fever with 40.6 °.
- Monday again contact with the doctor, where in the evening an abscess was found on the left hind leg, which was identified as the cause of the limping.
- blood values were still in a good range
- due to the abscess, cortisone was chosen (once) as well as antibiotics for three days
- new check of the blood values on Friday of the third week showed a renewed deterioration of the liver values, which were again not measurable (results on this were verbally communicated by the doctor)
- despite the worsened values, the dog eats again (I cook for him), the drinking behavior as well as urine/feces dropping behavior have normalized and the dog seems overall more energetic

**General remarks:**

- the dog shows a chronic irritation of the pancreas for a long time, which led to examine this also by ultrasound
- ultrasound showed that the pancreas, contrary to its normally flat shape, was spherically delineated
- liver also showed slight structural inhomogeneities, but this was considered normal for a dog of this age (age: twelve years)
- The doctor remarked that a tumorous problem could not be excluded, but he also remarked that massive improvement of the blood values due to infusions spoke against a tumor.

Now it is the case that the doctor here has already expressed uncertainties several times with regard to the symptoms, so that overall only a symptomatic treatment is carried out. I would therefore be interested to know what other causes could be for such a described course of the disease.

Blood values after infusion of the Thursday of the second week below as a picture:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Do you have maybe a list of values you could make a photo of or write into your question? Sometimes a kind of table is good to have all informations at place. I hope your dog will get a diagnose soon, to get help quickly!

Comment: Thank you for that remark I added more of information and hope I was more specific zhis time. If something still remains questionable please write me a comment.